# Jar с исходниками

Tags: java, maven, jar

Когда я создаю library (то есть jar, который будет подключаться другим приложением), Maven компилирует все, а потом создаёт уже jar.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы копиляция не происходила, а сразу упаковывались исходники в jar, а компиляция уже происходила в конечном приложении?

Comment: Что будет, если приложение, использующее вашу библиотеку, будет запущено на компьютере, на котором нет компилятора?

Comment: Библиотека будет скомпилирована, но не в проекте с самой библиотекой, а в проекте с приложением, которое её использует.

Comment: У вас так не получится, но вы можете прикрепить сурсы к жарнику, когда сделаете инстал в локальный репозиторий. Необходим специальный плагин.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понял суть вопроса.. чтобы иметь возможность собирать исходники в jar нужно добавить

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

сборка исходников будет происходить (когда) согласно phase..
в таком виде при сборке артефакта mvn package, создание jar с исходниками будет всегда происходить, т.к. validate исполняется ранее package.. если не нужно, чтобы создавался jar c исходниками при сборке артефакта, можно выставить фазу, которая идет после package, например, install, deploy..
независимо от фазы собрать исходники в jar можно командой mvn source:jar